# if statement print even when the statement is false?

Tags: php, if-statement

A seemingly simple question, but i'm not getting what is wrong with this one.
I have a file upload button that passes `?upload=success` in the URL.
I want to show a message when upload is completed; however, even when `$upload` is not set, I still get the message printed.

Here's the code:

```
$upload = "";
echo "Upload status: ".$upload;

if ($upload = "success") {
    echo "<h3>Upload completed <br></h3>";
} else {
    echo "";
}
```

I don't get why:

- when `$upload` is set to `""` the if statements go through and prints the string;
- when I complete an upload and I have `?upload=success`, the `echo "Upload status: ".$upload;` return nothing ( and obviously the `Upload completed` message still gets printed)

Thanks to anybody that will spend a minute to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Your are using assignment `=` instead of comparison `==`

```
if ($upload == "success") {
    echo "<h3>Upload completed <br></h3>";
} else {
    echo "";
}
```